# SXA component with rendering variant does not render if datasource is empty in the rendering

Tags: sxa, scriban

I am using an `SXA component` to render fields from current page. But it seems rendering variant renders fields only from datasource item.

In my case, datasource is empty as I need to render fields from current page item so it does not renders anything.

As a work around I am passing a dummy datasource and then in `scriban template`, I am assigning current page to current item like: i_item=i_page

Please suggest if there is a better solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make the rendering variant access the current page, mention the datasource "page:"   [image]

Comment: It worked. Thanks :)